# getting null values while iterating though list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```cs
EntityMapper<Datahub.Test_Consumer, Models.ConsumerBio> entObject = new EntityMapper<Datahub.Test_Consumer, Models.ConsumerBio>();
EntityMapper<Datahub.Test_Address, Models.ConsumerAddress> entObjectAdd = new EntityMapper<Datahub.Test_Address, Models.ConsumerAddress>();
EntityMapper<Datahub.Test_CardDetails, Models.ConsumerCardDetails> entObjectcard = new EntityMapper<Datahub.Test_CardDetails, Models.ConsumerCardDetails>();

List<Models.ConsumerBio> lstModConsumer = new List<Models.ConsumerBio>();           
List<Models.ConsumerAddress> lstobjConAdd = new List<Models.ConsumerAddress>();
List<Models.ConsumerCardDetails> lstobjConcard = new List<Models.ConsumerCardDetails>();

List<Datahub.Test_Consumer> lstDBConsumer = Datahub.DataLayer.GetAllConsumerList();
//  Models.ConsumerFamilyMember objConFMembers = new Models.ConsumerFamilyMember();           

foreach (var item in lstDBConsumer)
{
    foreach (var itemadd in item.Test_Address)
    {
        lstobjConAdd.Add(entObjectAdd.translate(itemadd));
    }

    foreach (var itemcard in item.Test_CardDetails)
    {
        lstobjConcard.Add(entObjectcard.translate(itemcard));                   
    }                

    lstModConsumer.Add(entObject.translate(item));
}
```

So, in above lstDBConsumer object I am getting all db values , but while iterating and assigning values to  lstModConsumer , I am getting all null values except my DOB filed. PLease tell me solution for this?

Comment: Please post your code for `translate`. You should inspect what `entObject.translate(item)` is returning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing child properties outside of your database context (which it appears you are) then you need to explicitly include them at the time of selection from the database.

Using an easy example from MS to show an include:

```
var blogs = new List<Blogs>();
var posts = new List<Posts>();
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    blogs = context.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Posts).ToList();
}
foreach(var p in blogs.Posts)
{
  posts.add(p);
}
```

IF however you are making assignment while still in the context of the DB connection, you can simply call the property. Enumeration happens automatically in that case as it still has context to the database to retrieve the properties.

```
var posts = new List<Posts>();
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Posts).ToList();
    foreach(var p in blogs.Posts)
    {
       posts.add(p);
    }
}
```

Entity Framework does not automatically load navigation properties (ie you wont automatically get the child objects of your object) due to a concept called Lazy Loading which is enabled by default.

Imaging you have a massive relational database and it automatically pulled all related objects when you did a simple query. Your very simple query could have huge implications if it auto loaded all relations. Could be a potential nightmare. Now there is a way to turn off lazy loading by that is out of the context of this question. Please refer to the following link for some more light reading and more detailed explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

In kind of a real world example to model, Imagine you had an interaction with two friends, John and Jane.

You talk with John on the phone and ask him what his plans are in the morning. He is attending a meeting at 9:30.

You then hangup and call Jane and tell her about John's plans for the day. You tell Jane about the 9:30 meeting and then she asks "Who all will be in the meeting?"

You have no clue because you didn't asks John when you talked to him. You KNOW that meetings have attendees but you have no idea who they are because you didn't ask John when you talked to him. You also know that meetings have agendas, locations, call in numbers, ect. It would be pretty inefficient to get all the explicit details of the meeting if you did not care about every detail. John would probably stop answering your phone calls if you operated this way every time you interacted with him.

BUT in a different scenario you had asked John who will be there (aka included the properties then you would have the answer) because you know that Jane will want to know when you talk to her later that day.

OR

If you were on a conference call with John and Jane and the question was asked (still within the database context when we wanted to find additional info) then the info would be readily available because John is on the call.

Hope this makes sense.